# Each Loops in Jade

Tags: pug

Just started exploring with Jade. I'm using the below code (example from Jade's documentation) to set up an unordered list. I would now like to nest an anchor tag within each list item (Home, About, Contact).
I've searched and cannot figure out how to do it. Any answers? Thanks in advance.

```
    ul
      each val in ['Home', 'About', 'Contact']
        li= val
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
ul
  each val in ["Home", "About", "Contact"]
      li
        a(href="#")= val
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you! That adds much clarity going forward.